# Where is the purchase requisition in odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I am looking for purchase requisition in odoo v12.
I found a PDF in odoo v11 and it includes purchase requisition.

[image: odoo v11 purchase requisition]

but in odoo v12, the purchase requisition disappear? Do I need to enable it? Where do I find it?

[image: Odoo v 12]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but about some software configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can find purchase requisition menu under Purchase.
make sure you have installed purchase_requisition module.

The name of purchase requisition menu is: Purchase Agreements

[image]